# how to retrieve specific value with where clause in C#

Tags: c#, sql

I have two table one table name is tbl_itemMaster  here attributes are ItypeNo and Itype

and another table name is tbl_Items   here attributes are ItmNo, ItemName, Qty, Price and ItypeNos as a FK from tbl_itemMaster.

i select items type from figure 3 and provide Item Name and Price then click add button and it save in the tbl_Item table with table ItypeNo 
[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pOr9U.png)

Here is our code. This code return -1 as ItypeNo
public int InsertItemsNo(receive recv)
        {

```
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

        cmd.Parameters.Add("USUsername", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = recv.Itypes;
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT ItypeNo FROM tbl_itemMaster WHERE Itype = @USUsername";

        int itemNo = Convert.ToInt32(conn.ExeNonQuery(cmd));

        return itemNo;


    }
```

Comment: What is `ExeNonQuery()` ? If you mean `ExecuteNonQuery()` it returns the number of rows affected, you should be using `ExecuteScalar()` to read the single value back.

Comment: ExecuteScalar: Connection property has not been initialized. System.Exception System.InvalidOperationException

Comment: Add `cmd.Connection = conn` or use the `SqlCommand()` ctor

Comment: your question to my answer is no longer relevant to your question.  I gave you the answer to your question on how to retrieve data from a query that has parameter

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the value of ItypeNo depending on the parameter in your WHERE clause in your query, you should do it like this.

```
using( SqlConnection connectionSTringHere = new SqlConnection("DataSource=ServerInstanceHere;Initial Catalog=DatabaseName;Integrated Security=True"))
{
    int itemNo =0; //edited
         SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT ItypeNo FROM tbl_itemMaster WHERE Itype = @USUsername",connectionSTringHere);

        cmd.Parameters.Add("@USUsername", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = recv.Itypes;

        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        da.fill(ds);
        foreach(DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
        {
            itemNo = Convert.ToInt32(dr["ItypeNo"].ToString());
        }
        return itemNo;
}
```

This is assuming that the ItypeNo in your database is an integer.

Edited: Please ServerInstance is whatever you use for login in SQL

DatabaseName is obviously what your database name is

Try to read further, don't ask everything in stackoverflow

Comment: Error 4 The name 'itemNo' does not exist in the current context

Comment: Error 5 The name 'itemNo' does not exist in the current context

Comment: even you added int itemNo =0;?

Comment: Error 1 The best overloaded method match for 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.SqlCommand(string, System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: man you're trying to ask everything now... I indicated already the variable that it should beyour connection string there

Comment: Error 2 Argument 2: cannot convert from 'DALL.DBconnection' to 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection'

Comment: Error 3 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter' does not contain a definition for 'fill' and no extension method 'fill' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: add using System.Data and using System.Data.SqlClient
on the very top of your code

Comment: System.Data.SqlClient  i have already use it no response same problem

Comment: ItypeNo appears to be a primary key so there is no need for a loop/adapter

Comment: hello give me your mail address i want to give you my project and you may solved it if you have time enough. it will be very helpful for me. thanks   in advance

Comment: how much would you pay me for your project?